# mod_rewrite does not rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)$ index.php?Agent=$1 [QSA]
```

theoretically any visitor to my site using the format:

```
www.site.com/user/username
```

should be directed to:

```
www.site.com/index.php?Agent=username
```

they are instead being treated as if /user is a real directory and as if /user/username is a valid file and exists (which it does not). Any ideas?

### EDIT #1

I have modified my htaccess slightly and even stripped off the /user requirement, the following .htaccess file causes and 500 error, even when visiting the primary domain alone (www.site.com):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?Agent=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `mod_rewrite` is configured properly?

Comment: Do you have a directory called `user` in that root directory?

Comment: You might also want to add `[L]` to that `[QSA]` if that is the end of rewriting.

Comment: @Tim Cooper - mod_rewrite is enabled, yes

Comment: @Orbling - no there is not a directory named /root, there wouldn't need to be based on the rewrite rule

Comment: @JM4: I said called `user` in the directory that is the document base, it could interfere if there was.

Comment: @orbling - error in typing, thinking about another comment while replying to yours. No - there is no directory named user

Comment: @JM4: Those last two requests will both match the same stuff and due to the lack of last matching will follow through, causing a conflict.  The penultimate rule, is that intended to catch files that exist with a `.php` extension?

Comment: ultimately, i want my file to first, check if a real file or directory exists, if it does, ignore it, 2) if the file has a php extension, remove it, 3) rewrite the entire URL if the first set of rules dont match so the Agent ID can be used

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f <- there's a missing space here. If you have access to it, check the apache error_log, it will describe why you're getting an error 500.

Comment: @Capsule - there is a space in the text above and in the actual file for the line you reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> they are instead being treated as if /user is a real directory and as if /user/username is a valid file and exists (which it does not).

What exactly do you mean like this? What does it show?

Do you want to **rewrite** or **redirect?

Rewrite = call www.site.com/index.php?Agent=username when the user enters www.site.com/user/username

Redirect = redirect the user to the other URL so their address field says www.site.com/index.php?Agent=username

Right now, your code should rewrite, not redirect, which is probably what you want. Just checking...

Your problem might be that the username you're testing with contains capital letters. Add NC to make the match case insensitive.

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)$ index.php?Agent=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

If you want to allow other characters than just the letters a-z, you can either add more characters to character class, or just write `(.+)` to match any character.

**Edit**

As per the question below, I think the infinite redirect happens because the rule is triggered again (and again) because the rewrites matches the new index.php request. Simply checking that the target of the redirect isn't a file should solve that. (-f = "is file". ! = negate condition.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: when a username is being input (e.g. www.site.com/username) it is looking for a file username instead of using the formatting rewrite as listed. rewrite, correct. I have tried using No case, last line, rewrite/redirect, nothing (also used (.+) but nothing changing!

Comment: @nitrok2k01 - I **Might** have found part of the issue, however when i remove the /user/ clause ( RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?Agent=$1 [QSA,NC,L,R] ) it gives a 500 infinite redirect error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It should work.  I am using pretty much that exact line for my rewrite.  Here's what I've got:

```
RewriteRule ^history/(.+)?$ history.php?display_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note the "L" flag, which means mod_rewrite should stop at this point, and not process any other rewrite rules.  Do you have any other rewrite rules after this one?

Are you putting this in .htaccess?  Make sure it's being processed at all.  Put some random junk in there and load a page. Apache should show you an error page, complaining about a server misconfiguration.  If it doesn't, it's not even looking at your .htaccess file.  Make sure in your apache configuration, "AllowOverride" is set to "FileInfo Options" for the directory in which this webpage lives.

Comment: I have used as last line and without, doesn't seem to make a difference. I have put it both in htaccess as well as the virtual host configuration file, no difference (vhost.conf). I know it is reading the htaccess though because in the latest edit, I am receiving a 500 redirect error.

Comment: I see your edit.  Just out of curiosity, does it work when you remove the fist two Rewrite conditions, and the first Rewrite rule?  If you remove everything but the rule in question, just for testing, to try and narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark but I suggest that you recheck your Apache configuration file `apache2.conf` file to make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Look for a line like this : 
`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

and change it to:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

EDIT: Then restart your web server for the changes to take effect!

Hope this helps!

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and is used for other portions of my htaccess file. thanks for the suggestion though!